# How to set frame if orientation change?

Tags: ios, swift

Can anyone give me hint how to set frame for scrollview if orientation change?Right Now this what i am doing to show images.Any help would be Helpful.

```
  mainScrollView.frame = self.view.frame

    for i in 0 ..< images.count {

        let imageView = UIImageView()
        imageView.image = images[i].image
        imageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
        let xPosition = self.view.frame.width * CGFloat(i)
        imageView.frame = CGRect(x: xPosition, y: 0, width: self.mainScrollView.frame.width, height: self.mainScrollView.frame.height)
        mainScrollView.contentSize.width = mainScrollView.frame.width * CGFloat(i + 1)
        mainScrollView.addSubview(imageView)

    }
    if let index = images.index(where: { $0.imageName == selectedImageName }){
        let position = CGPoint(x: (mainScrollView.frame.width * CGFloat(index)), y: 0)
        mainScrollView.setContentOffset(position, animated: true)
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Trigger this notification in `VDL` method

```
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(ViewController.rotated), name: NSNotification.Name.UIDeviceOrientationDidChange, object: nil)
```

And implement this below method

```
func rotated() {
    if(UIDeviceOrientationIsLandscape(UIDevice.current.orientation))
    {
        print("landscape")
    }

    if(UIDeviceOrientationIsPortrait(UIDevice.current.orientation))
    {
        print("Portrait")
    }
}
```

Comment: You are good.Thanks for help.it worked.but i used this method " func willRotate(to toInterfaceOrientation: UIInterfaceOrientation, duration: TimeInterval){}" i am curious why it's not worked in this method.

Comment: @JayPatel Actually many delegates methods are deprecated from `ios 9` as I supposed so triggering notification is the latest one approach. There are some more method..`viewWillTransit` and `viewwillOrientation` as I remembering but all deprecated now.